# Hoeffding's inequality for unequal sums of two random variables

Tags: probability, inequality

Hoeffding's inequality for sampling a random distribution X with mean $\mu_x$ and range $R_x$ for N times is:

$$P(|\sum^N_i x_i - N\mu_x| \geq t) \leq 2\exp\bigg(-\frac{2t^2}{N R_x^2}\bigg)$$

This is nice because we can get a bound over the empirical mean by choosing $t$ so that we simplify the N:

$$P(N |\hat{\mu}_x - \mu_x| \geq tN) \leq 2\exp\bigg(-\frac{2t^2N^2}{N R_x^2}\bigg)$$
$$P(|\hat{\mu}_x - \mu_x| \geq t) \leq 2\exp\bigg(-\frac{2t^2N}{R_x^2}\bigg)$$

Where with $\hat{\mu}$ I've indicated the empirical mean. We can make a similar bound when summing two sets of samples, each of size N, coming from two independent distributions, one from X and one from Y (with mean $\mu_y$ and range $R_y$):

$$P(|\hat{\mu}_x + \hat{\mu}_y - \mu_y - \mu_x| \geq t) \leq 2\exp\bigg(-\frac{2t^2N}{R_x^2 + R_y^2}\bigg)$$

These bounds have the property that as the number N of samples increases, the bound itself becomes tighter, i.e. for any given $t$, the bound for N+1 samples is tighter than for just N.

However, I'm interested in the case where I'm sampling $X$ N times, but $Y$ N+1 times. In this case I am unable to do the simplification, so I cannot get a "pretty" looking bound. However, it makes sense to me that the bound would still be tighter, somewhere in between sampling both N times and sampling both N+1 times. Would it be possible to prove that it is the case (or that at least the bound for N doesn't break by sampling Y one more time), even without a nice formula for the bound itself?